# Different render results in 2.79b and 2.80rc1

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

[image: Left:2.79b Right:2.80rc1]

Left:2.79b

Right:2.80rc1

Both images are rendered using cycles, from the same .blend file whith no changes made.

The 2.80 version is pale / washed out compared to 2.79b.

What could be the cause of this? 
Some setting somewhere, not contained in the .blend file?

Comment: "*What could be the cause of this?*" The fact that you are using two completely different versions of the software, enough has changed to reasonably expect different results. Also jumping versions with the same working files is not really a good practice

Comment: Fair enough I suppose. I guess changing to 2.80 mid-project is a Bad Idea then.

Comment: It's probably because of the changes in color management. Blender 2.8 likely uses Filmic as a replacement for the old Film one. Check in the Render tab. You'd probably want to use Filmic and set the look to one with higher contrast.

Comment: Thanks gtzkw, playing around with the settings under color management seems promising.

Another thing I've played with is the bump strength in the materials. Increasing that seems to bring the result closer to what I want.